# Any method to bypass Cross Domain issue? (for personal use only)

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I want to know if there any method to bypass the cross domain issue?

It's only for personal use. what I want to do is just extract some data from my page(under control) and fill them into a external site's form (included into my page with iframe) other wise I have to copy & past them manually, that's painful.

I tried many method but with no lucky.

Comment: I have no control over the external site.

Comment: Huh? You want to inject details from your page into a third party page? What should happen here is that the third party hosts your content in an iframe on their page, you can't just add your content to theirs.

Comment: I think more detail will help your question allot here.
Would server side scripting assist you?

Comment: You could develop a browser-plugin or write a userscript. Both run with extended rights so they don't have to care about SOP

Answer (score 0):

Use YQL as a proxy:
[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url=%27http://website.com/query/path%27&format=json&callback=call_me](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20json%20where%20url=%27http://website.com/query/path%27&format=json&callback=call_me)

That gives you a JSON-P call.
... Then implement function `call_me(json_object) { ...`

Remove the "callback" parameter if you want plain JSON.